# Pandas conditional cumsum with stop when hit the limits and continue when below it

Tags: python, pandas

There is a pd series.
For the column 'a',when the cumsum is bigger than k(k=2),any positive data will be drop(no more than add to the cumsum result),if the cumsum is lower than -k, any negative data will be drop. I have realized this function with a loop,but it is too slow.How can I modify this function? Thank you very much.

I am considering to improve the function with expanding function. Such as this. But it is wrong.Because the cumsum is depending on the previous data.

```
def c_sum(x):
    s=x.sum()
    k=2
    if (s<k+1 )and (s>-k-1):
        return s
    elif s>k:
        return 2
    else:
        return -2

%time sig['x']=p

pd.expanding_apply(sig['a'],c_sum)
```

=============the following code is right but slow==========

```
sig = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,2,[100,4]),columns=['a','b','c','d'],\
index=pd.date_range('6/12/2012', periods=100,freq='5min'))

def mytest():
    global count
    for i in sig['a']:
        temp=0
        if count>1:
            temp=sig['d'].iloc[count-1]      
        s=(temp+i)
        if np.abs(s)<(k+1):
            sig['d'].iloc[count]= s
        else:          
            sig['d'].iloc[count]=temp
        count=count+1
```

Comment: Say the input goes `1 1 1 -1`. Should the output go `1 2 2 2` or `1 2 2 1`?

Comment: yes, output go 1 2 2 1

Comment: If I understand correctly, your expanding_apply works fine for me, although the new syntax (for version 0.18.0) is `sig.expanding().apply(c_sum)`

Comment: I suspect expanding/apply is the way to go although possibly doing a numpy function or using numba would be faster, if expanding/apply is still too slow.

Comment: but it seems there is something wrong with expanding function. input  1 1 1 -1 and output 1 2 2 2, but I want to get output 1 2 2 1. because when I set the limit to sum ,I can not change the original series, and the new c_sum depends on the previous one. It means when the input is 1 1 1  1 -1 -1 ,with the c_sum the output will be 1 2 2 2 2 2 . Thanks for JohnE's comments.,with a numpy funchtion it is faster. Still I want to know how to solve it with expanding function.